# jqplot width between graph bars

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqplot

How can I modify the distance between the bars in jqplot. There is too much space between them when there are less elements on it. Here are 2 images, one with some bars showing and the second one with less bars showing.

[image]

[image]

The less bars that show, the bigger the difference between bars. I want to be able to change this WITHOUT making the bars fatter. I like the bars like they are right now but I want to make the grid width size smaller between the bar and the grid lines in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the barPadding to a negative value

```
seriesDefaults: {
  renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
  rendererOptions: {
    barPadding: -20
  }
}
```

Comment: #paul : is there any solutions that sets container's width dynamically ? i mean what if container is too small to accommodate bars.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
seriesDefaults: {
     renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
     rendererOptions: {                        
           barMargin: 8                        
     }
},
```

Comment: I had some problems with this as well and found that things weren't refreshing all that well when I changed some of these options right away.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should set barWidth.

```
seriesDefaults: { renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer, rendererOptions: {
        barWidth: 15
        } },
```